# Given the shape below , describe the Solid of revolution obtained by rotating the curve about x axis?

Tags: solid-geometry

> Given the shape below  , describe  the  Solid of revolution    obtained by rotating the curve about x axis?

[image]

Scale is not important

> I need a visual 3D- graphing  for this problem , please !!
>
> Is there any website that can help me in familiar problems?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It would look a bit like a top (the toy) with no handle.

Comment: What do you mean by "describe"?

Comment: @5xum  name or type of the solid ,  sphere , cone , etc  "hybrid solid"

Comment: @Medo I don't think it has a name. It's a cylinder with half a ball missing on one side, and a cone put on top on the other.

Comment: @5xum  Brilliant answer,  i get the same result but after some time , now how could i make a visual graphing for this solid ? Any idea

Comment: @Medo <ou can use Geogebra

Comment: @Surb  how can i do that?  Can you help me,  please

Comment: you can download the program here: https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en
and then you can make your figure and finally rotate it.

Comment: you can use this link: https://ggbm.at/KA5BpkjF and move the rotation angle $\alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an animation showing the rotation:
It is made with [Geogebra](https://geogebra.org/?lang=en) and an interactive version can be found [here](https://ggbm.at/KA5BpkjF)

[image]